How add a landscape page and adjust KOMA script header/footer accordingly?
I need to put a wide table in a landscape page and adjusting the document's header and footer.
I spent the last couple of hours to research how to achieve that. Using (pdf)lscape doesn't do the trick as the header and footer are 90° rotated.
Then I found that I can easily switch the orientation using:
\cleardoublepage
\newpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=landscape,pagesize}
\recalctypearea

This changes the orientation, correctly.
I still do have a couple of problems with the landscape oriented page that I can't find a solution for:

The KOMA script header width remains set up for portrait pages.
The footer disappears completely.
The text width remains up for portrait pages.

Here is my MWE:
\documentclass[
  11pt,
  a4paper,
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifPDFTeX
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xetex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\fi
\usepackage{lmodern}
\ifPDFTeX\else  
    % xetex/luatex font selection
    \setmainfont[]{Arial}
    \setsansfont[]{Arial}
\fi

\usepackage[margin=2cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em} % prevent overfull lines


\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[
    automark,
    headsepline,
    footsepline,
  ]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles

\ihead{Name}
\ohead{Title}
%\chead{}

\def\dateversion{\leavevmode\hbox{\the\year\twodigits\month\twodigits\day}}
\def\twodigits#1{\ifnum#1<10 0\fi\the#1}

\cfoot[]{}
\ofoot{Page \pagemark{} of \pageref*{LastPage}}
\ifoot{Report\_\dateversion}



\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names,table,xcdraw]{xcolor}


\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}


\section{First section}

\lipsum

\cleardoublepage

\newpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=landscape,pagesize}
\recalctypearea
\newgeometry{margin=2cm,bottom=3cm}



\section{Section with table}

Here is a very long sentence that spans two lines but breaks before the landscape page has actually ended, just because something is off and I don't know what.

\begin{table}[!ht]
\begin{tabular}{@{} | >{\bfseries}l | p{6cm} | p{8cm} | p{6cm} | >{\centering}p{2cm} | >{\centering}p{1cm} | @{}}
    \hline
    {\textbf{Nr.}} & {\textbf{Name}}             & {\textbf{Description}}      & {\textbf{Proof}}               & {\textbf{Cat.}} & {\textbf{Prio}} \tabularnewline
    \hline
    L 1.1        & Foo & Foo is bar & FooBar Receipt & must & 1 \tabularnewline
    \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}



\newpage
\KOMAoptions{paper={portrait},pagesize}
\recalctypearea
\newgeometry{margin=2cm,bottom=3cm}

\section{Some other section}

\lipsum

\end{document}

The output:


koma script has its own mechanisms for customising page size, I'm not sure mixing them with geometry is totally safe. (also but unrelated you don't need inputenc or textpos  in current latex, and why use sans serif with luatex but serif with pdftex?)

also on fonts: don't load lmodern with a unicode engine. this should be in the if pdftex bit ....

you say this typesets the header and footer correctly but then you say the footer disappears altogether ....

I thought that KOMA internally used geometry. But thanks to you, I found that this is not the case.
As for inputenc/lmodern. I am writing my document using md and quarto. Thus, some uncommon things are in the source. Tried to get rid of them all, but I obviously missed some things.

Note, the answer to the similar question works not only, if you want to add a page with different page size but also with different orientation only. As an alternative see https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-en/HowTo_A3_landscape_to_A4/ (English) resp. https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-de/HowTo_A3_landscape_to_A4/ (German) in the KOMA-Script Wiki.

BTW: Option pagesize is the default. UTF8 is also the default for all engines for several years. And textcomp also shouldn't be needed anymore.

According to David Carlisle's comment using KOMA and geometry might cause some hickups. This is what happens here.
The answer to the question "Mixing KOMAscript and geometry" has the answer to this issue:

For several release KOMA-Script provides an undocumented option usegeometry to interact with package geometry. Since KOMA-Script 3.22 this is an documented option (of package typearea). It translates the page settings of package typearea into page settings of package geometry and passes them, e.g., as options to geometry.

So, passing usegeometry to your KOMA class will solve all 3 problems I had in my question.
\documentclass[
  11pt,
  a4paper,
  usegeometry %% <-- solution
]{scrartcl}


Your question and the answer makes me wonder: you get the english version of the KOMAscript manual with texdoc scrguide-en on the command line. German version scrguide-de. Documentation about usegeometry on p. 471. The whole book is really worth reading!
